# Get path name for NextJS route for dynamic routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Is there a way to get the name for the specific route for a page?

I'm getting a list of products and each products gets its own page:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const productCatalog: Array<ProductType> = await getAllProducts()
  return { props: { productCatalog } }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const productCatalog: Array<ProductType> = await getAllProducts()

  const dynamicFiles: Array<Object> = productCatalog.map(
    (product: ProductType) => ({
      params: { pid: product.id },
    })
  )

  return {
    paths: dynamicFiles,
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

When NextJS generates the static pages, is there a way to get product specific data?  I'm currently passing in the entire product catalog in the example *then* filtering by the single product.

I tried to filter by the route but the router was not recognized.  So something like this:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const router: NextRouter = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  const productCatalog: Array<ProductType> = await getAllProducts()

  const productData: ProductType = productCatalog.filter(
    (product: ProductType) => product.id == pid
  )[0]  

  return { props: { productData } }
}
```

Comment: You can access the dynamic param through `context` object in `getStaticProps` to fetch the data for each particular product. For example, if the page is called `[pid].js` then you can access `context.params.pid`.

Comment: Thanks @ivanatias! This is what I was looking for.  I see this now in the docs.  Feel free to make this an answer to I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the dynamic page param in `getStaticProps` through `context` object's `params` property. For example, if the page is called `[pid].js` then you can access `context.params.pid`:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { pid } = context.params  

  // Fetch the specific product corresponding to that id
  ...
}
```